# Quick triangle inequality question

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ so if we have complex numbers like z and i, is the following true? $|z-i|=|z+(-i)|\leq |z|+|-i|= |z|+|i|$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true for complex numbers. The proof of the triangle inequality is slightly different for complex numbers but it is not too bad. Let $x,y \in \Bbb{C}$. Then $$\begin{align}|x-y|^2 = (x-y)(\overline{x}-\overline{y}) \\ = |x^2|-\overline{x}y-x\overline{y}+|y|^2 \\ \leq |x|^2+2|x||y|+|y|^2 \\ = (|x|+|y|)^2 \end{align}$$ And hence $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$. In particular, this is true for $x=z$ and $y=i$. In this proof I used the fact that $-(\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}) \leq 2|x||y|$. Can you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly true. You have also $|a-b|\leq |a|+|b|$ and $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$ for each $(a,b)$. But think of it geometrically : $|a-b|$ (resp. $|a+b|$) is the "length" of the vector going from the point of cordinates $(0,0)$ to the point of coordinates $(x,y$ where $x$ and $y$ are respectively real and imaginary parts of $|a-b|$ (resp. of $|a+b|$)...